# Как добавить ряд проверок, прежде чем сделать запись в файл?

Tags: php

У меня есть такой код, который из формы записывает введенные в поле input данные каждый раз с новой строки:

```
    if(isset($_POST['fav']))
    {
        $uniqueid = $_POST['uniqueid'];
        file_put_contents('us/db/fav/'.$us_id.'', $uniqueid."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
        echo "<meta http-equiv=refresh content='0; url=page.php'>";
        exit();
    }

<form action='' name='' method='post'>
<input name='uniqueid' type='text' value=''>
<button name='fav' type='submit' value='Search'>Search</button>
</form>
```

Этот код у меня работает прекрасно. Подскажите пожалуйста, но как добавить ряд следующих проверок с условиями, прежде чем сделать запись в файл? Когда пользователь вводит данные в поле input, то первая проверка:

1. совпадают ли введенные в поле `input` данные с Названием какого-либо файла в папке `admin/db/rec/`

- Если нет полного совпадения, то никаких действий;
- Если есть полное совпадение, то перейти к следующей проверке:

2. Совпадают ли введенные в поле input данные с какой-либо строкой, записанной в файле `us/db/fav/$us_id`

- Если нет, то записать введенные в поле input данные в файл `us/db/fav/$us_id`;
- Если да, то никаких действий.

Comment: Мышки плакали, кололись, но продолжали есть кактус :)

Comment: *"Как добавить ряд проверок, прежде чем сделать запись в файл?"* --- ну, есть `if`'ы, которые вы знаете уже, судя по коду.... в чём проблема - не ясно

Comment: В целом непонятно, какие именно затруднения. Все эти операции уже выполнялись в предыдущих вопросах. Как проверить файл на существование можно узнать из гугля. как прочитать файл уже сто раз отвечали. Какие конкретно проблемы с этими проверками?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сил смотреть на эти мучения нет никаких

```
// подключаемся к базе данных
$db = new PDO("sqlite:".__DIR__."/database.sql");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// проверяем пользователя
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->execute([$user_id]);
$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();
if (!$exists) {
    die("Пользователь не найден\n");
}
// вставляем значение
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO fav (user_id, value) VALUES (?,?)" );
$stmt->execute([$user_id,$value]);
```

В этом коде уже есть все проверки. [Рабочая демонстрация](https://phpize.online/s/e4)

Как видно, если подставить несуществующего пользователя, то никаких добавлений не будет.
Если попытаться добавить уже существующее у этого пользователя значение, никаких добавлений не будет